# Can I capture trap messages along with $LINE_NO?

Tags: shell-script, trap

I have a code like:

```
trap 'error ${LINENO} ${BASH_COMMAND}' ERR
```

I want to capture error message along with this. Is there any built-in variable for printing error message?

Answer (score 0):

Error handling in shell scripts is rather simple. The only standardised ways of detecting any kind of issue are the **return code** of a command (non-zero in case of error) and content printed to **standard error** (file descriptor 2). Standard error will by default be printed to your terminal. If you need to pass it to `error`, for example because error messages get drowned in other output, you could for example replace the current shell with one which [saves standard error to a temporary file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002):

```
trap 'rm -f "${stderr_output_file}"' EXIT
stderr_output_file="$(mktemp)"
exec 2>"${stderr_output_file}"
[the rest of your program]
```